# Asking curl to skip missing files

Tags: curl

**Is there any way to tell `curl` not to download a file when it does not exist on the server?**

I am using my Mac OS X shell to download a few files with `curl`.

The command goes:

```
curl -s -# "http://URL/session[1-12].pdf" -o "Slides/session#1.pdf";
```

Is there any way I can tell `curl` to skip, say, `session4.pdf`, when that file does not actually exist? It downloads empty 2KB files instead by default.

P.S. I hope I am posting this at the right place, apologies if it should go to the Apple StackExchange branch. Since it's shell, I though this would be more appropriate.

Comment: Tried the `-f` (`--fail`) switch?

Comment: By the way, why are you setting the progress bar (`-#`) while asking for absolutely no output (`-s`)?

Comment: That worked: I had missed the `-f` option. And yes, the `-#` is unnecessary here, it's a leftover from previous tests. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use the `-f, --fail` option [to ask curl to silently skip errors](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-f) and it will not produce empty files.

In other words, your command should be:

```
curl -f -s -# "http://URL/session[1-12].pdf" -o "Slides/session#1.pdf";
```